# Satisfy: The second derivative is $0$ for all $x$; $dy/ dx = 1$ when $x = 0$; and $x = 0$ when $y = 0.$

Tags: integration, derivatives

> Does any function satisfy all of the following?
>
> - The second derivative is $0$ for all $x$
> - $dy/dx = 1$ when $x = 0$
> - $x = 0$ when $y = 0$
>
> If yes, give an example. If no, show why not.

Comment: What did you find difficult about this? What did you find out about it (show your work) and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Try a straight line that passes through the origin.

Finding the slope of the line should not be difficult.